# Is there a way to specify partial custom types in type annotations?

Tags: elm, algebraic-data-types, structural-typing

Is there a way to specify partial custom types in type annotations?

For instance, if I have my type aliases this way: `func : { a | foo : String }` can I have this function:

```
when : Bool -> msg -> msg -> msg
when ok msgTrue msgFalse = 
    if ok then 
        msgTrue 
    else 
        msgFalse
```

and I would like to do something like this:

```
when : Bool -> (msg | NoOp) -> msg
when ok msg = 
    if ok then
        msg 
    else
        NoOp
```

where we know `msg` has at least `NoOp` value

Comment: The short answer is no, you cannot pattern match in function annotations, but I'm wondering if you can give a more concrete example or reason why you would like this type of functionality. There's probably another way to reach your goal.

Comment: What you're asking for (I think) is a structurally typed sum type/variant/tagged union. This does not exist in Elm, so no, it's not possible. OCaml has a feature like this, called [polymorphic variants](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-400/manual006.html#toc36). But because of subtleties with subtyping it's pretty complicated to use, and very error-prone since you can't exhaustively pattern match on an unknown type and unless you add type annotations on everything it's very easy to sneak in a typo as well.

Comment: Your use of the terms "function annotation" and "pattern marching" was also way off. I've tried to replace them with what I think you mean, but there's a decent chance I've misunderstood you, so please correct me if I have.